# Razor components: Can I create multiple (upstream rendering) sections in the Main layout?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Currently I am working on a project in Blazor Web Assembly. Here I want to create a sperate block/section where I can render different bootstrap modals from different Blazor pages. Can I achieve it by creating a new layout component class, adds a new RenderFragment property and inherit from it?

Update1:
Is It possible to create multiple sections (as in asp.net/mvc razor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the search for the solution of my problem I found that Blazor pages doesn't render upstream but we can achieve upstream rendering by using [Mr. Steve Sanderson's approach](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16009#issuecomment-390932846).

But I used another approach for my scenario which is as follows:

Created a class and injected as scope:

```
public interface IUIBlocks
{
    RenderFragment? ModalsBlock { get; }

    event EventHandler<OnUpdateEventArgs> OnValueUpdate;

    void SetModalsBlock(RenderFragment blockBody);
}

public class UIBlocks : IValueUpdator, IUIBlocks
{
    public RenderFragment? ModalsBlock { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler<OnUpdateEventArgs> OnValueUpdate;

    public void SetModalsBlock(RenderFragment blockBody)
    {
        ModalsBlock = blockBody;
        OnValueUpdate?.Invoke(this, new OnUpdateEventArgs
        {
            CallerType = GetType(),
            CallingMethod = nameof(SetModalsBlock),
            CallingObject = this
        });
    }
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUIBlocks, UIBlocks>();
```

In MainLayout.razor injected the UIBlocks instance and placed ModalsBlock where I wanted it to be placed

```
@inject IUIBlocks BlocksService
...
</div>
@BlocksService.ModalsBlock
...
```

Now, Created a Razor Component as ModalsBlock:

```
@inject IUIBlocks Blocks



@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        Blocks.SetModalsBlock(ChildContent);
        if (firstRender)
        {
        }

        return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

and now I can use it in any Razor Component like this:

```
<_ModalsBlock>
    <div class="modal fade>
    ...
    </div>
</_ModalsBlock>
```